# how to call haveibeenpwned api php json v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

im want to call haveibeenpwned v3 API,
here is my code

```
<script>
        $.ajax({
        url:"https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v3/breachedaccount/brian.c@softnet.co.id",
        headers: { 'Content-type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded', 'hibp-api-key': 'my-key'},
        async: false,
            datatype:'application/json',
            success:function(data){
                alert("a");
            },
            error:function(data){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });
</script>
```

but i always get this this error at the console

```
{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v3/breachedaccount/brian.c@softnet.co.id'."}
```

pls help me if you ever use haveibeenpwned.com

i already doing this way with another api, this is my first time with headers

i expect the json output

Comment: i didnt get CORS error, just {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Comment: Are you certain? Which browser are you testing with? See my answer below anyway, according to the docs you will not be able to access the API via AJAX, because of CORS restrictions

Answer (score 0):

You likely have some other errors in your console too which are more relevant than the one you posted - including, I expect, a CORS-related error.

According to https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v3#CORS you may have a problem because

> "CORS is only supported for non-authenticated APIs".

...and according to https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v3#Authorisation

> Authorisation is required for all APIs that enable searching HIBP by email address...The key is then passed in a "hibp-api-key" header

Therefore the endpoint you are trying to search is one requiring authentication/authorisation and as such you are not allowed to make a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) (cross-origin ) AJAX request to it.

In conclusion you will need to connect to this API via your server-side code instead.